# Why Angular 7 app is throwing error while build?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on angular 7 app. It's working fine on localhost on port 4200. But when I am trying to build it by saying: ng build --prod it's throwing error like...

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-vzrure\src\environments\environment.prod.ts path in file replacements does not exist.
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as $ from "jquery";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  public ngOnInit() {
    $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(":first");
      }
      next
        .children(":first-child")
        .clone()
        .appendTo($(this));

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(":first");
        }

        next
          .children(":first-child")
          .clone()
          .appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: update @angular/cli

Comment: ok.............

Comment: now another error occuring i.e., ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.

Comment: show you  src/app/app.component.ts file

Comment: why are you including jQuery into your Angular app?

Comment: now I have updated everything even then getting same error

Answer (score 0):

First of all i will not suggest using `jquery` with `angular` as angular itself have all capabilities of `jquery`  and in more optimized  form.

But even then if you want to use then......

you are importing `jquery` in wrong way :

To get jquery with angular you should do :
First, install jQuery using npm as follows

```
npm install jquery — save
```

and include the path to `jQuery` as follows

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

then use jQuery:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

(or)

```
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have a file “environments/environment.prod.ts”